# What does this weird directory listing in Linux mean?

Tags: linux, centos, shell

I was clearing out some old sites on a CentOS server (MediaTemple DV) and stumbled upon this when doing an `ls -lha` :
http://skitch.com/callmeed/ntgb5/weird-directory-listing

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20100119-cdgske12wthd63q4adk1uumr1e.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20100119-cdgske12wthd63q4adk1uumr1e.jpg)

All the file names are flashing and I'm not able to remove any of the files with `rm -f`

What does this mean? Drive/disk problems?

Answer (score 9):

You've got a bit of filesystem corruption there.  Take the machine offline as soon as possible and fsck that filesystem.

Comment: Filesystem might already be fscked.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "take the machine offline"? Shut down all network apps/services?

Comment: @Callmeed - most likely you won't be able to fsck a mounted disk (depending on your filesystem).  You'll probably need to boot of a live/rescue cd to fsck it.

Comment: If this isn't the / filesystem then just unmount it and fsck it.  If it is / then you will need to boot into single user mode with it mounted ro or use a liveCD